Install specific version of R langauge (R4.x.x) on a docker image based on ubuntu
I have a docker file that successfully grabs R and installs it but whenever I run the docker file, it just takes the latest version of R. Now I want to install just specific version of R (R 4.2.3 to be exact) but i dont seem to find a easy nice solution
Please note my image has to be based on Ubuntu 20.04. I am aware of r.rocker series of images from docker hub.
Here is my docker file code for the reference:
FROM ubuntu:20.04

#ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests \
    ca-certificates software-properties-common gnupg2 gnupg1 \
    && apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9 \
    && add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/'

RUN apt-get -y install r-base r-base-dev

RUN apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
    curl \
    libxml2-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libsqlite3-dev \
    libmariadbd-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    unixodbc-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libsodium-dev


See for example https://docs.posit.co/resources/install-r-source.html

After looking at here and some trail and error, I finally made a generic docker image that all the R 4 versions can be installed on, just change the R version on ENV
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV R_VERSION=4.2.3 \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends \
    ca-certificates \
    build-essential \
    gfortran \
    libreadline-dev \
    xorg-dev \
    libbz2-dev \
    liblzma-dev \
    curl \
    libxml2-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libsqlite3-dev \
    libmariadbd-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    unixodbc-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libsodium-dev \
    wget \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Download and install R
RUN wget -c https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-4/R-${R_VERSION}.tar.gz \
    && tar -xf R-${R_VERSION}.tar.gz \
    && cd R-${R_VERSION} \
    && ./configure \
    && make -j$(nproc) \
    && make install \
    && cd .. \
    && rm -rf R-${R_VERSION} R-${R_VERSION}.tar.gz


You could invert the problem and start from the appropriate Docker images:
$ docker run --rm -ti r-base:4.4.1 R --version | head -1
R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14) -- "Race for Your Life"
$ docker run --rm -ti r-base:4.3.3 R --version | head -1
R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29) -- "Angel Food Cake"
$ docker run --rm -ti r-base:4.2.3 R --version | head -1
R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15) -- "Shortstop Beagle"
$ docker run --rm -ti r-base:4.1.3 R --version | head -1
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10) -- "One Push-Up"
$ docker run --rm -ti r-base:4.0.5 R --version | head -1
R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31) -- "Shake and Throw"
$ 

The r-base images go back to a few more R 3.* versions if you need those.
Edit  If you are on Ubuntu and have the CRAN mirror of Ubunty binaries configure then you can point at 4.2.3 via a version constraint.  I am on 24.04 and I don't see 4.2.3 but I do see 4.3.1. An older base may see 4.2.3.  Worst case ... you can use a from-source installation.

As I explained in the question, it has to be based on ubuntu image because of strict configuration of the project

Then yolu are out of luck (in general), I fear, because "in general" no repo gives you mulltiple version of a package .... but you are in luck because CRAN does via its R mirror.  Run apt-cache policy r-base-core and then use =X.Y.Z in the install command for the r-base(-core) package(s).  The binaries are still there, but you may need trial and error to get the correct base distribution.  It may be "jammy" (22.04) for some, and "focal" (20.04) for others.  I would not recommend using 20.04 for new projects today by the way.
